# Additional asterix note in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to put a double asterisk under this chart in Plotly. Below you can see code and chart

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes*", "whale**", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
) |> 
  layout(annotations = 
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1, 
                text = "Note: * The tallest animal.", 
                showarrow = F, 
                xref='paper', 
                yref='paper')
  )
```

[image]

Now I want to put an **additional note below** the note shown on the plot.

The text should be `"Note: ** Тhe longest animal "`. I tryed with this code below but is not working.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes*", "whale**", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
) |> 
  layout(annotations = 
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1, 
                text = "Note: * The tallest animal.",
                text = Note: ** Тhe longest animal,  # <----This line of code
                showarrow = F, 
                xref='paper', 
                yref='paper')
  )
```

So can anybody help how to solve this problem additional note below first note ?

Comment: If you want two note below `girraffes*`, does `text = "Note: * The tallest animal. \n Note: ** Тhe longest animal"` works? You may let `y = -.131`.